# First fundamental form, where's the $dt$ coming from?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tangent-spaces

It's been a while since I have done formal calculus and I am getting lost in a small detail when studying the first fundamental form of a regular surface $S$.

I am seeing this formulation in a [set of notes](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node28.html) I am reading:
$$
\begin{align}
ds = \left|\frac{d{\bf r}}{dt}\right|dt =
\left|{\bf r}_u\frac{du}{dt}+{\bf r}_v\frac{dv}{dt}\right|dt
&=\sqrt{({\bf r}_{u}\dot{u}+{\bf
r}_{v}\dot{v})\cdot({\bf r}_{u}\dot{u}+{\bf r}_{v}\dot{v})}\,dt\\
&= \sqrt{Edu^2 + 2Fdudv +
Gdv^2}\tag{3.11}
\end{align}
$$

I understand the intent, and I understand how/why the tangent to the curve is equal to the sum of the surface tangents as it is merely the chain rule. What I can't seem to recall is how and why the $dt$ pops up outside of the equation. Like $\frac{dr(t)}{dt}$ is trivially the tangent vector, and thus $\left|\frac{dr(t)}{dt}\right|$  is the magnitude, where is that second $dt$ term coming from?

Comment: An equation like $\frac{{\rm d}s}{{\rm d}t}=f$ is often written as an equation of two differentials, as ${\rm d}s=f\,{\rm d}t$. If you have ${\rm d}s$ on the left side, then intuitively it represents an infinitesimal quantity and the right side must likewise be some kind of differential, in this case a multiple of ${\rm d}t$. Intuitively, this tells us how to the infinitesimal change ${\rm d}s$ in arclength is proportional to the infinitesimal change ${\rm d}t$ in the parameter $t$ (that proportion between the two itself varying as a function $t$, of course).

Comment: Oh I see that makes sense.